# Campo gravando como Null no Firestore Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firestore

Estou tentando gravar um documento dentro de outro documento (nested documents) no Flutter com o Firestore. O modelo é um imóvel que possui alguns campos, e junto aos campos uma coleção de comodos, que por sua vez possuem apenas um Id (imovelId) e descrição (descricao).

Eu consegui gravar o Imóvel, no entanto quando tento gravar um comodo na coleção de comodos dentro de um imóvel, a ***descrição*** do comodo sempre fica "***null***".

A estrutura é parecida com isso:

```
[Imóvel]
    |-> imovelId: 'id do imovel'
    |-> endereco: 'endereco do imovel'
    |-> data:     'data da vistoria'
    |
    |->[Comodos]
           |
           |-> comodoId: 'valor do id deste comodo'
           |-> descricao: 'ex. Quarto'
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a entender o que estou fazendo errado?

modelo Imovel:

```
class Imovel {
  String imovelId;
  String endereco;
  String data;

  List<dynamic> comodos = [];

  Imovel(
      {this.imovelId, this.endereco, this.data, this.luz, this.agua, this.gas});

  Imovel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    imovelId = json['imovelId'];
    endereco = json['endereco'];
    data = json['data'];

  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['imovelId'] = this.imovelId;
    data['endereco'] = this.endereco;
    data['data'] = this.data;
    data['comodos'] = this.comodos;
    return data;
  }
}

class Comodo {
  String comodoId;
  String descricao;

  Comodo({this.comodoId, this.descricao});

  Comodo.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    comodoId = json['comodoId'];
    descricao = json['descricao'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['comodoId'] = this.comodoId;
    data['descricao'] = this.descricao;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Provider:

```
class ImovelProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  var firestoreService = FirestoreService();
  String _imovelId;
  String _endereco;
  String _data;

  String _comodoId;
  String _descricao;
  var uuid = Uuid();

  // Getters
  String get imovelId => _imovelId;
  String get endereco => _endereco;
  String get data => _data;
  String get comodoId => _comodoId;
  String get descricao => _descricao;


  carregarValoresComodo(Comodo comodo) {
    _comodoId = comodo.comodoId;
    _descricao = comodo.descricao;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  salvarComodo() {
    if (_comodoId == null) {
      var novoComodo = Comodo(comodoId: Uuid().v4(), descricao: descricao);
      firestoreService.salvarComodo(novoComodo, Imovel(imovelId: imovelId));
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      var comodoExistente = Comodo(
        comodoId: _comodoId,
        descricao: _descricao,
      );
      firestoreService.salvarComodo(
          comodoExistente, Imovel(imovelId: _imovelId));
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

Service:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:jc_vistoria/models/imovel.dart';

class FirestoreService {
  FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;



  Future<void> salvarComodo(Comodo comodo, Imovel imovel) {
    return _db
        .collection("imoveis")
        .doc(imovel.imovelId)
        .collection('comodos')
        .doc(comodo.comodoId)
        .set(comodo.toMap());
  }

}
```

Screen edit_comodo.dart:

```
 class EditComodo extends StatefulWidget {
  final Comodo comodo;
  final Imovel imovel;

  EditComodo([this.comodo, this.imovel]);

  @override
  _EditComodoState createState() => _EditComodoState();
}

class _EditComodoState extends State<EditComodo> {
  final descricaoController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    descricaoController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (widget.comodo == null) {
      //Novo imovel
      descricaoController.text = "";

      new Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
        final imovelProvider =
            Provider.of<ImovelProvider>(context, listen: false);
        imovelProvider.carregarValoresComodo(Comodo());
      });
    } else {
      //Imovel existente
      descricaoController.text = widget.comodo.descricao;

      // atualiza os estados
      new Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
        final imovelProvider =
            Provider.of<ImovelProvider>(context, listen: false);
        imovelProvider.carregarValoresComodo(widget.comodo);
      });
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final imovelProvider = Provider.of<ImovelProvider>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Adicionar/Editar comodos')),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(28.0),
        child: ListView(children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Descrição:',
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            decoration:
                InputDecoration(hintText: "Digite a descrição deste comodo..."),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            controller: descricaoController,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
            RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.green,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
                imovelProvider.salvarComodo();
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.save),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 10),
            RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              textColor: Colors.black,
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Icon(Icons.border_top),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 10),
            RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.red,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
                imovelProvider.removerComodo(widget.comodo, widget.imovel);
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
            )
          ])
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente criar um [exemplo **mínimo**, completo e verificável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-completo-e-verific%c3%a1vel?r=SearchResults&s=1|131.4936)

Comment: Obrigado Costamilam, já editei e removi as partes que acredito serem desnecessárias.

Comment: No `salvarComodo` do seu provider, no `if` a descrição vem da variável `descricao`, já no `else` vem de `_descricao`, um dois dois não está errado? Debugue o código e verifique se no serviço `comodo.descricao` não está nulo, se sim está recebendo errado, então verifique no código que o chama, fazendo o mesmo processo até achar a fonte do problema

Comment: Infelizmente nao, Costamilam. Eu já tentei _descricao, e também descricao. Todas as vezes é salva a descricao como null.

Comment: Para o objeto Imovel, este sistema de nomenclatura de variáveis está funcionando normal @Costamilam

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a falha. Faltava definir a função no TextFormField:

```
onChanged: (value) {
            imovelProvider.mudarDescricao(value);
          }),
```